Failed unit test task on gradle with a build server, but working locally on my computer
So I have been working on implementing CI/CD pipelines for an android application using a windows build server and when I run unit test task on the build server it fails with the following
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.writeBuffer(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:98)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:85)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
> Task :AuthorizationModule:testQaDebugUnitTest FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Common
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Common

but it never fails when I run it locally on my device, all the prerequisites for gradle building are the same on both my device and the build server.
I tried matching both environments but it still fails when running unit tests tasks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are there any differences between the JVMs being used to run gradle on each machine? ie different versions (17 vs 21) or different releases (oracle vs openjdk)?
